# Texture colors off when rendered in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, colors, textures

[image]

On the left is how the texture appears when viewing the PNG in any photo viewer/editor. And on the right is the same texture rendered on to a quad in OpenGL. As you can see the colors differ quite a bit. Does anyone know the cause, and how to fix this?

I'm using LibGDX (which uses Lwjgl on Windows), and it's just a simple sprite set to the mentioned texture file.

Comment: If there's no transformation done to the colors, my bet would be on sRGB colorspace utilized properly in the viewer but not in your app.

Comment: Well, apart from sRGB, gamma might be interpreted differently by different viewers. PNG file format contains additional gamma information, and stripping it might be beneficial, as in [link1](http://f6design.com/journal/2006/12/01/fixing-png-gamma/), [link2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush#Reducing_filesize_by_removing_color-correction_data). I am not an expert in the field, but I'd expect that to help.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I disabled the 'convert to sRGB' option when saving in Adobe Illustrator, and the result is the same. I just tried opening the PNG in Internet Explorer and Chrome and it looks how it appears on OpenGL (right), whereas windows image viewer, photoshop, and adobe illustrator shows the colors as appears on the left. Confused.

Comment: Actually, I think it has something to do with color management and color profiles, and nothing to do with OpenGL. Though I have no idea how to make it looks the same across all applications.

Comment: @terryhau: Well, Adobe Photoshop of course uses color profiles to display everything color corrected. Most standard programs don't care about it and just pass through RGB values to the graphics card. The way to fix this on current systems, is by adding color management to your program. The only viable long term solution would be to force color managements deep down in the operating systems graphics infrastructure; programs should use a *contact color space* instead of RGB.